# Terraform AWS Log group subscription filter pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Is it possible to have this:

`{$.error = "*httpStatus\": \"500\"*"}`

subscription filter pattern in Terraform? I currently have it as:

`filter_pattern  = "{$.error = \"*httpStatus\\\": \\\"500*\"}"`

and applying it yields an error:

`Error: Error creating Cloudwatch log subscription filter: InvalidParameterException: Invalid character(s) in term '\'`

Edit: it's possible through the AWS interface, but I need it on Terraform:
[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63668422/getting-invalidparameterexception-while-trying-to-setup-cloudwatch-log-filter-vi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a mistyped `\` as it says in the error.